# Redirect all requests to a directory and it's subdirectories to a file inside the directory, using Apache2 server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The Document folders are structured like this

```
/var/wwww/ (root)
    java/
    ...
    php/
        projectone/
            controller/
            view/
                index.php
            ...
        projecttwo/
            ...
```

I want all requests to /php/projectone or it's subfolders to redirect to /php/projectone/view/index.php, while requests to /php/projecttwo and other folders should not be redirected.

I believe using mod_rewrite is the way, however, I still haven't achieved what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place an `.htaccess` inside project one folder with the following rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php/projectone/

RewriteRule ^(view/)?index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . view/index.php [L]
```

And you can repeat that for any other project folders you have. by changing the `RewriteBase`.

Comment: That didn't work as it is, but after removing the second RewriteCond and replacing the RewriteRule's for `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ view/index\.php`, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @drakenation you should not remove the first condition, unless you want existent files to also be redirected to the `index.php`. The first 2 conditions are telling the system that you want to redirect to index.php only if the file or directory does not exist. And the first `RewriteRule` will basically do nothing if the URL contains `index.php`